# UploadAsync to S3 bucket from Blazor WASM causing a 403 Forbidden error

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to upload images to an S3 bucket from a Blazor WASM project using the AWS SDK.  I can upload successfully from a Windows Forms app so I'm confident that my bucket access is correctly setup.  My problem arises from not having access to the local device's file structure so the vast majority of examples to accomplish uploading with C# don't apply to my issue as I can't use the filepath of the image I'm trying to upload.  Instead I need to read the file in to memory and upload it from there.

This code works for me in the Windows Forms project:

```
using (IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client("accesskey", "secretaccesskey", s3Config))
{

    TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility(client);
    TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()                
    request.BucketName = bucketName;                
    request.Key = s3Filename; 
    request.FilePath = localFilePath; 
    utility.Upload(request);                
}
```

This is the similar code in my Blazor WASM project:

```
private async void HandleFileSelected(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> selectedFiles;
    selectedFiles = e.GetMultipleFiles();
    foreach (var file in selectedFiles)
    {
        var resizedFile = await file.RequestImageFileAsync(file.ContentType, 1024, 768);

        var buf = new byte[resizedFile.Size];
        using (var stream = resizedFile.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: 1024 * 768))
        {
            await stream.ReadAsync(buf); // copy the stream to the buffer

            var s3Config = new AmazonS3Config
            {
                MaxErrorRetry = 5,
                RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1,
                AllowAutoRedirect = false
            };

            using (IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client("access key", "secretaccesskey", s3Config))
            {

                TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility(client);
                TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();
           
                request.BucketName = "mybucketname";                
                request.Key = "image.jpg"; 
                request.InputStream = stream;
                utility.UploadAsync(request); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get a 403 forbidden error on the UploadAsync line with the URL "https://mybucketname.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image.jpg?uploads" being the address it is apparently forbidden from accessing.  No such file has been uploaded at the time this error triggers.

Any suggestions would be appreciated as this has been causing me problems for two days now and I feel it isn't as complicated a problem as I'm finding it...

Edit:

I've tried the following code in a Windows Forms app and it works perfectly. But the second I put it in Blazor I get the 403 forbidden errors along with the error "request signature does not match the signature you provided".

```
public static async Task<bool> UploadFileAsync(
   IAmazonS3 client,
   string bucketName,
   string objectName,
   Stream stream)
{
    var request = new PutObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = objectName,
        InputStream = stream,
    };

    var response = await client.PutObjectAsync(request);
    if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Successfully uploaded {objectName} to {bucketName}.");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Could not upload {objectName} to {bucketName}.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

What is it that I'm doing in Blazor that is causing such problems?

Comment: Do you have CORS configured on the bucket (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors.html)?

Comment: Yes CORS is all set up correctly.  I don't receive any errors to suggest the issue lies there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using PutObjectAsync.  Here's an example lifted from the AWS SDK website.  I've done it with modifications to the code and works fine.  I see you are trying to upload several files.  I would try just adding one file.  Also use the S3 exception handling.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_PutObject_section.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found that page while trying to find a solution and edited the code to use a stream instead of the file path.  However I still get the same 403 error plus a new one:   'Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.'   This only seems to occur when using async methods in blazor. I notice other solutions talk about the system clock not matching AWS servers so throwing the algorithm out of sync. Could that be part of my problem or am I barking up the wrong tree?